# Making line in QQplot for a model

Tags: r

I have created a linear mixed model that then viewed on a Normal Q-Q plot using the following code in R:

```r
qqnorm(resid(Model))
```

I want to add a line to the plot since there isn't one but I am having a hard time finding the right code for it even though I bet it's an easy one-liner. Can anyone help please?

Comment: `abline(a = 0, b = 1)`?

Comment: @AllanCameron the Q-Q line isn't necessarily scaled appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
qqnorm(residuals(fm1))
qqline(residuals(fm1),col=2)
```

Or

```
lattice::qqmath(fm1)
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I'm just curious, what does the col=2 in the code mean?

Comment: it makes the line red.

Comment: If this solved your problem you are encouraged to click the checkmark to accept it ...